# Placing price bounds on MtGox market depth api request

Tags: mtgox, api, market-depth

I'm making an order book for MtGox, but the market depth file is huge and I'm really only interested in values near the inside prices.

Is it possible to place price bounds on the mtgox market depth request `http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/depth/fetch` and if so how?